# Pass UserId to the Model

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, viewdata

So I have a simple web app where I can create a user (UserModel) and it returns that user ID. The user then has the ability to enter multiple instances or records of a specific item type, in this case a geographic location (LocationModel). The LocationModel has a UserId property that I need to set when the location is created.

The ActionLink for creating a user is User/Create/id=[userid]

The code in the controller is currently.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Create(string id)
{
     return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(LocationModel model)
{
   //CODE TO SAVE MODEL
}
```

My questions is how to pass the user id so that I can get it into the model in order to relate the two. I was going to try to pass it in the ViewBag and render it in a Hidden field but was thinking that someone has to have a more elegant solution than this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the `UserId` on the model, and pass the model to the view:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Create(string id)
{
    return View(new LocationModel{UserId = id});
}
```

Then render the UserId property as a hidden field in the View, so it will get included on your `model` parameter when the form is POSTed.

```
@model LocationModel
@using (Html.BeginForm(...)) {
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.UserId)
    ...
}
```